# How do I connect a computer far away from the monitor?

Tags: usb, display, hdmi, signal

I have an architectural practise where we use relatively powerful computers that are difficult to replicate on lap tops. Flexibility in the office is key, so I was wondering if it is possible to place all the computers in one room (on a rack for example) and connect the screens and keyboards in the office to them.
This way, when we need to assemble a team that works together on a project, we would just need to switch the HDMI cables and the persons computer would migrate to any screen we would want.
I am aware of limitations on USB and HDMI cables, so I would like to know if anyone has done this before or have any suggestions?
If laptops were powerful enough, we would get mobility in the office which is common in most offices but as architects we have multicore computers and at the moment move them around to get the flexibility we need.
Really appreciate any help in this regard.
Thanks
Luis

Answer (score 3):

If everyone is using laptops, then you can connect to the workstations using any remote desktop tool, like Window's built in Remote Desktop, or use VNC, or even TeamViewer.  These options are far more flexible than running cables.

Comment: You could always get repeaters for the cables, but I agree with Keltari. RDP sessions would be the way to go. Stick the power systems in an air cooled area and everyone can remote in with wifi or network cable.

Answer (score 2):

KVM Extenders are used to connect a console(keyboard,mouse/screen) to a computer box, with a long cable e.g. cat5 cable.

You can combine a KVM Extender to a KVM switch. So you can have a set of computer boxes, a long cable, could be 30 metres away, and then a keyboard monitor and mouse.

Comment: there might be kvm extenders that are wireless these days

Comment: kvm extenders are good if a comp makes a loud noise too.

Comment: KVMs, including IP KVMs are great, but they arent 100% troublefree.